# nodejs request.body is not showing any parameters

Tags: node.js, express

Below is my `nodejs` replit and inside `routes/home.js` when I send any post request from `postman` then `console.log(request.body)` returns undefined.

[REPLIT](https://repl.it/@zafar_saleem/DarkgrayConcernedWifi)

```
api.post('/', function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you should put relevant code actually in the post, rather than in a link to a code sharing site.  It's more likely to be useful for the long haul.

The answer to your question is that you're not using the `body-parser` middleware to setup the body of the POST request.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Home = require('./routes/home');

const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/api/0.1/home', Home);

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
```

Comment: Thanks but request.body is empty object.

Comment: @null Change your POST form type to make sure it's either urlencoded or JSON, or else add the appropriate bodyparser type, I only provided two as an example.